# Is the average velocity of an object going down an inclined ramp equal to the instantaneous velocity of the object at the midpoint of the ramp?

Tags: physics

So, I need to verify whether or not the average velocity of an object going down an inclined ramp is equal the instantaneous speed of the object in the midpoint, and I need to figure out a simple way to explain it as well.

Comment: Assuming it's accelerating due to gravity then I wouldn't expect it to be. Such a point exists by the mean value theorem but it's unlikely to be the midpoint.

Comment: @IsaacLee  Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details [HERE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 4):

Velocity increases linearly with time. This means that average velocity occurs at the midpoint in time, which is definitely not the same as the midpoint in space.

Comment: So if an object going down a 2.4-meter ramp takes 2.85 seconds, if we find the average speed it would be 0.84m/s, so at 1.425 seconds, the instantaneous velocity of the object will be the same as the average speed 0.84m/s?

Comment: @Isaac: That is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Since the motion is at constant acceleration $a$, we have

- $s=at^2/2\implies t=\sqrt{\frac{2s}a}$

and therefore

- $v=at=\sqrt{2sa}$

which is not linear.